# how to find the package to which a particular r function belongs given the package isn't installed on the PC

Tags: r

I want to combine multiple ggplots using **ggarrange()** function in **ggpubr package**. After running the following code where p1 and p2 are ggplots;

```
`ggarrange(p1, p2, nrow = 2)`
```

**It returns the following error**:

*Error in `purrr::map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `**obj_is_vector()**`:
**! could not find function "obj_is_vector"***

**Running the below function also returns the same error**.

```
plot_grid(plotlist = list(p1, p2), nrow = 2)
```

I tried to pinpoint the relevant package to install so the function `object_is_vector()` would be accessible to these parent functions. Most of the google searches seem to point to the package ***vctrs* **. I loaded it on to my machine, but still the error isn't solved. In addition, I have used the `**findFunction()**` in the package, **sos** which returns the name and the path of the package that includes a given function if only the package is already installed on the machine but not necessarily loaded. So, if faced a similar problem where **the function is known** but the package isn't readily identifiable and isn't installed on one's machine what source/method if any should one resort to?

Comment: This shouldn't happen. You somehow messed up your installed packages. My guess is that there are version conflicts. (I often see those, they can result from the huge dependency trees of tidyverse packages and are ultimately a result of shortcomings of R's package dependency management). You should update/reinstall all installed packages.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I have updated all the installed packages, and the issue has disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

You could `grep` the loaded namespace to see if it exists somewhere.

```
> library(vctrs)  ## to demonstrate 
> sapply(loadedNamespaces(), \(n) 
+        any(grepl('^obj_is_vector$', ls(getNamespace(n), all.names=TRUE)))) |> 
+   which()
vctrs 
   10
```

Comment: The error itself claims it does not exist. So this wont help. For this to work, the function has to exist. ie detach the vctrs package and try `grep`ing and you will note that the function does not exist.

Comment: @Onyambu In this case, internet search should help, e.g. `system('w3m https://duckduckgo.com/?q=obj_is_vector | head -n 30')` and reinstall identified package as *@Roland* suggests.

Comment: Not really if the package is installed but not loaded you do not need internet search. Just use `sub(".*library/(\\w+)/.*", '\\1', help(obj_is_vector)[1])`. For example in your case, you loaded the `vctrs` package. That is because you knew the function was in that package. But sometimes you copy code from someplace, you install the packages, but you forgot to load them. Then you run the code and get an error, yet you do not know the package to load

Comment: Also it seems OP problem is broken package installation. The packages mentions do import vctrs and thus should be installed automatically. Note that it need not be loaded for the packages to work, but they are throwing an error which should not be the case. Eg dplyr imports vctr but if you load dplyr, vctrs is not loaded, yet works with no issue. There is a problem with scoping and namespace in OP

Comment: @Onyambu the library call resembles what packages should do that depend on vctrs. In the real situation we won't use it, of course. If it's not there, OP should reinstall all packages they use in the code.